# How to implement a side sheet in Android

Tags: java, android

The Material Design website tells about side sheets (non modal) which can slide from the side and hide back (https://material.io/components/sheets-side, the option for tablets). Despite hours of research I couldn't find any information on how  to implement them in Android (except for navigation drawers, but they  are of no interest). Unfortunately, the "Implementation" section on the page is empty.

There also was a similar question without an answer on this site.

Does anyone know how to do it in Java (Adroid)? The sheet should push the contents of the screen to the side when opened. Is there any common solution for it?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the component has been released yet.